# xceed messagebox hidden when app focus is lost

Tags: wpf, xceed

I'm using `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox` and when the MessageBox gets hidden by another app while it's opened (Minimizing the app also works), it's no longer displayed, it stays behind everything. This means if the MessageBox was in the app border, I can no longer see it nor move the MainWindow. So I can only force close.

Is there a way to force the MessageBox to always be on top of the application?

The MessageBox is created this way :

```
private static MessageBoxResult Show(string message, string title, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage image)
{
    if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        return MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.Windows[0], message, title, button, image);


    return (MessageBoxResult) Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
        new Func<MessageBoxResult>(() => MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.Windows[0], message, title, button, image)));

}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? Having the same problem at the moment...

Comment: Sorry for the late answer : I contacted the Xceed's technical support and after a few emails, they noticed this was a known bug and it is going to be fixed in the next release, so you just need to wait for the 2.7 update (The Pro one (2.9) already has the fix)